# Getting mockito exception in Keystore Junit test case

Tags: java, maven, mockito, keystore, powermockito

I am trying to run a Junit for uploading ssl certificate using the Keystore. But while mocking the keystore during the execution of test case I am facing error. I am using IntelliJ IDE.

Here is my Junit class UtilityTest.java

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;

@PrepareForTest(KeyStore.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.security.*"})
public class UtilityTest {
    @InjectMocks
    Utility utility;
    @Test
    public void uploadTSCertificate() {
        MockMultipartFile file  = new MockMultipartFile("file","hello.txt",
                MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE,"Hello, World!".getBytes());

        try {
            KeyStore keyStoreMock = mock(KeyStore.class);
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(KeyStore.class, invocation -> keyStoreMock);
            PowerMockito.when(KeyStore.getInstance(any())).thenReturn(keyStoreMock);
            PowerMockito.doNothing().when(keyStoreMock).load(any(InputStream.class), any(char[].class));
            X509Certificate cert = Mockito.mock(X509Certificate.class);
            PowerMockito.when(keyStoreMock.getCertificate(any())).thenReturn(cert);
            utility.uploadServerCertificate(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Pom.xml

```
<powermock.api.version>1.7.4</powermock.api.version>
        <powermock.module.version>1.5.1</powermock.module.version>
        <powermock.common.version>1.6.5</powermock.common.version>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.api.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.module.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito-common</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.common.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Error:**
[image]

I have also deleted maven repository from my local machine and rebuild agian, still facing same issue.

Comment: possible you can try other way around, ```PowerMockito.doReturn(keyStoreMock).when(<method call>)``` i could not replicate all in PC due to dependency.

Comment: @prostýčlověk I tried this too, still getting same error